# Different behavior for NOT IN vs NOT EXISTS

Tags: sql, postgresql, not-exists, notin

I am receiving different results from the following two queries and do not understand why. Shouldn't this `NOT IN` query return the same result as the `NOT EXISTS` query?

```
SELECT p.pid, p.pname, w.salary
FROM Person p, worksFor w
WHERE p.pid = w.pid AND NOT EXISTS (SELECT *
                    FROM worksFor w1,Knows k
                    WHERE w1.pid = k.pid1 AND w1.cname = w.cname AND w1.pid <> w.pid AND k.pid2 = w.pid);

SELECT p.pid, p.pname, w.salary
FROM Person p, worksFor w
WHERE p.pid = w.pid AND 1 NOT IN (SELECT 1
                    FROM worksFor w1, Knows k
                    WHERE w1.pid = k.pid1 AND w1.cname = w.cname AND w1.pid <> w.pid AND k.pid2 = w.pid);
```

```
 pid  |  pname   | salary 
------+----------+--------
 1002 | Vidya    |  45000
 1007 | Danielle |  50000
 1010 | Linda    |  55000
 1011 | Nick     |  70000
 1013 | Lisa     |  55000
 1016 | YinYue   |  55000
 1018 | Arif     |  50000
 1019 | John     |  50000

 pid  |  pname   | salary 
------+----------+--------
 1007 | Danielle |  50000
 1012 | Eric     |  50000
 1017 | Latha    |  60000
 1018 | Arif     |  50000
 1019 | John     |  50000
(5 rows)
```

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name, that is not true: `select 1 NOT IN (SELECT 1 from cell_per where line_id > 200); t`

Comment: Pretty sure this comes down to difference in handling `NULL` or the comparison differences as outlined here [Subquery Expressions](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-subquery.html#FUNCTIONS-SUBQUERY-NOTIN). It would help to see the output of the subquery when executed as a stand alone query.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name: For the record: `SELECT 1 NOT IN (SELECT 1 WHERE FALSE);` --> `true`. You forgot the case where the subquery returns *no row*.

Answer (score 5):

The two given queries **should** produce the same result since you have `SELECT 1` with `NOT IN` (which makes little sense for `IN` / `NOT IN` to begin with).

`NOT EXISTS` and `NOT IN` **differ** when `null` values are involved in the comparison:

```
SELECT NOT EXISTS (SELECT NULL::int);  -- false
SELECT 1 NOT IN   (SELECT NULL::int);  -- null !
```

`NOT EXISTS` is `false` if the bracket expression returns any rows.
`NOT IN` differs when `NULL` values are involved. The logic behind it: `null` values are considered "unknown", their true value might match after all, we just don't know. So the result is `null` instead of `false`.

[`NOT IN` is discouraged for this use case](https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Don%27t_Do_This#Don.27t_use_NOT_IN).
`NOT EXISTS` is almost always the **better tool** with subqueries. Typically faster, too.

See:

- [Select rows which are not present in other table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19363481/select-rows-which-are-not-present-in-other-table/19364694#19364694)

My guess is that your displayed `NOT IN` query differs from what you actually tested. A typical "equivalent" `NOT IN` formulation for the given `NOT EXISTS` clause would be:

```sql
...
AND (w.cname, w.pid) NOT IN (
   SELECT w1.cname, k.pid2
   FROM   worksFor w1, Knows k
   WHERE  w1.pid = k.pid1
   AND    w1.pid <> w.pid);
```

*"Equivalent"* in quotes, because it differs with `null` values.

Comment: Displayed queries and outputs are what I had tested

Comment: @WalnutWaxwing: Unless something changed in the database between calls, that is logically impossible. Or something is (was) seriously broken in your DB.